# How to make a single bounding box

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, bounding-box

I am doing text-detection using OCR and in my program, if a photo has multiple text, it makes multiple bounding boxes. I was wondering if there was a way to combine all the boxes and make a new cropped output image of the text. PS: I'm using the EAST deep learning text. The problem is it detects the texts in the image but if the texts are a little further apart, it creates 2 or 3 images based on that original image and I am trying to look for a way for it to combine these 2-3 crops into 1.

```
(newW, newH) = (args["width"], args["height"])
rW = W / float(newW)
rH = H / float(newH)

image = cv2.resize(image, (newW, newH))
(H, W) = image.shape[:2]


layerNames = [
    "feature_fusion/Conv_7/Sigmoid",
    "feature_fusion/concat_3"]


print("[INFO] loading EAST text detector...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNet(args["east"])


blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, 1.0, (W, H),
                             (123.68, 116.78, 103.94), swapRB=True, 
crop=False)
start = time.time()
net.setInput(blob)
(scores, geometry) = net.forward(layerNames)
end = time.time()

print("[INFO] text detection took {:.6f} seconds".format(end - start))


(numRows, numCols) = scores.shape[2:4]
rects = []
confidences = []

for y in range(0, numRows):

scoresData = scores[0, 0, y]
xData0 = geometry[0, 0, y]
xData1 = geometry[0, 1, y]
xData2 = geometry[0, 2, y]
xData3 = geometry[0, 3, y]
anglesData = geometry[0, 4, y]


for x in range(0, numCols):

    if scoresData[x] < args["min_confidence"]:
    continue


    (offsetX, offsetY) = (x * 4.0, y * 4.0)


    angle = anglesData[x]
    cos = np.cos(angle)
    sin = np.sin(angle)


    h = xData0[x] + xData2[x]
    w = xData1[x] + xData3[x]


    endX = int(offsetX + (cos * xData1[x]) + (sin * xData2[x]))
    endY = int(offsetY - (sin * xData1[x]) + (cos * xData2[x]))
    startX = int(endX - w)
    startY = int(endY - h)


    rects.append((startX, startY, endX, endY))
    confidences.append(scoresData[x])


boxes = non_max_suppression(np.array(rects), probs=confidences)

for number, (startX, startY, endX, endY) in enumerate(boxes):

    startX = int(startX * rW)
    startY = int(startY * rH)
    endX = int(endX * rW)
    endY = int(endY * rH)

   Final = orig[startY:endY, startX:endX]
   cv2.imshow("Text Detection", Final)
   cv2.waitKey(0)

   cv2.imwrite("crop{}.jpg".format(number), Final)
```

Comment: if you get all `x,y` then all of them are in region `min(x), min(y), max(x), max(y)`

Comment: The thing is the startX startY endX and endY will generate multiple boxes for an image with multiple text. I want it to just generate 1 box with all the text in it.

Comment: get all `startX startY endX and endY`, find `min(), max()` and you have one box.